# File manager detects Android device but gvfs folder is empty. How can I access the MTP device from terminal?

Tags: android, ubuntu, mtp

Directories `/run/user/1000/gvfs` and `~/.gvfs` are emtpy and non-existing, respectively. My graphical file manager (Thunar) is able to detect and access the internal and external memory of the device.

Command `gvfs-mount -l` yields:

```
Volume(0): SAMSUNG Android
 Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorMTP)
 Mount(0): SAMSUNG Android -> mtp://[usb:002,003]/
   Type: GProxyShadowMount (GProxyVolumeMonitorMTP)
```

Where can I find the mount point of the device to access it from the command line? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to install [gvfs-fuse](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gvfsd-fuse.1.html):

> **gvfsd-fuse** maintains a fuse mount to make gvfs backends available to POSIX applications. The mount point for the fuse filesystem is provided by the [PATH] argument.
>
> **gvfsd-fuse** is normally started by **gvfsd**(1). In this case, the mount point is **$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR**/gvfs or **$HOME**/.gvfs.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77592) is a great explanation:

> `/run/user/$uid/gvfs` or `~$user/.gvfs` is the mount point for the FUSE interface to GVFS.
>
> ...
>
> The GVFS-FUSE gateway makes GVFS filesystem drivers accessible to all applications, not just the ones using Gnome libraries.

---

Execute following commands

```
sudo apt install gvfs-fuse
pkill thunar
pkill gvfs
```

and run Thunar again.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue with Android 11. Solved it by going into the phone's 'Settings - Connected devices - USB' and selecting 'File Transfer' which was apparently disabled by default.